# I'm trying to convert Oracle to PostgreSQL. How to write for loop in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, oracle, plpgsql

I'm trying to convert Oracle to PostgreSQL. I am getting
**function instr(character varying, text, integer, integer) does not exist**
error in line number 2.

```
FOR CNT IN 1 .. UPPER_LIMIT LOOP
      POS := INSTR(V_STR, SEPERATOR, 1, CNT);
      ST  := SUBSTR(V_STR, V_START, (POS - V_START));
      V_START := POS + V_LEN;
      V_SPLITSTR (CNT) := ST;
      V_SPLITSTR.EXTEND;
    END LOOP;
```

Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please describe, what the functionality you want to achieve. Code migration is not just find-and-replace

Comment: You most probably don't need to write your own split function. Postgres has several quite powerful split functions built-in. You should take a step back and describe us what exactly your function should do. Instead of reposting the same question in different versions, please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables.

Comment: What is the purpose of the function?

Comment: I have used split function in many packages it is very difficult add split functions built function for each packages so am using writting split function.                                            W_SPLIT_MSG := FN_SPLIT(P_OTP_KEY, '|');                                                                        
I have wrote declared split function like this in my package.

Comment: Again: you most probably do not need to write your own split function. Show us what your current function does (with sample input and output data) and there is a good chance Postgres has a split function you can use.

Comment: @snehapai In Postgres, `W_SPLIT_MSG := FN_SPLIT(P_OTP_KEY, '|');` is probably just `W_SPLIT_MSG := string_to_array(P_OTP_KEY, '|')`. Take some time and look through [what functions Postgres has available](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions.html). It is very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you'll have to look up the Oracle function, for example [instr](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm), and see if [Postgres has an equivalent](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions.html). There is a site to help with migrations, [SQLines](https://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-postgresql).

[While `strpos` is close, it can only find the first index](https://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-postgresql/instr). Fortunately there is a more powerful function  `split_part` which does what both `instr` and `substr` do.

You'll also have to use [Postgres Arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/arrays.html) instead of Oracle Arrays. Something like this.

```
FOR CNT IN 1 .. UPPER_LIMIT LOOP
  v_splitstr := v_splitstr || split_part(V_STR, SEPARATOR, CNT);
END LOOP;
```

But the whole loop can be replaced with just [`string_to_array`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER), if the `upper_limit` isn't really necessary.

```
v_splitstr := string_to_array(v_str, separator);
```

Comment: I'm getting error for array_push. like this syntax error at or near "array_push"please help me to slove this.

Comment: @snehapai Sorry, it's `array_append` or simply `array := array || thing`